# appcache is being cached?

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-appcache

When I check google chrome for cached files ( chrome://appcache-internals/ ) I find this(among other files):

```
Manifest,   http://localhost/MUHMobile/cache.appcache   1.5 kB
```

Does this mean that my appcache file is getting cached? I wouldn't want it to be cached.

Anyone got any tips on how NOT to cache this file?

Comment: Why should it not be cached?

Comment: If the .appcache file is cached, you will never be notified when an update occures, because the browser will always check the old, stored cache, instead of the new cache. In other words, no new files will be loaded.

Comment: When the browser is online it will check if the appcache file is updated. There is also an api available to check if there are updates available.

Comment: Yes, I know this. But that won't work if the appcache is cached. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I was simply wondering if the appcache file is cached or that it just appears in chromes appcache-internals for some other reason

Comment: If the appcache wasn't cached, how would the browser know what to do when offline? Any change to that file will invalidate the whole cache – that's how you are expected to deal with it. (Can't wait till the new offline stuff materialises – this is rubbish!)

Comment: I see. What new stuff? =)